# mod_rewrite doesn't work when accessing directory

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm developing a web site using php.
And I want to use first directory name of URL as parameter for php.

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/(.*)$ xyz/$2?first-dir=$1 [L]
```

When I access `http://example.com/aa/b/`,
`/xyz/b/index.php` is executed with parameter `first-dir=aa`.
And URL in address bar of broweser is `http://example.com/aa/b/` (same as input URL).

But when I access `http://example.com/aa/b` (without tailing `/`),
URL in address bar become `http://example.com/xyz/b/?first-dir=aa`.
I don't want to show this rewrited URL to users.

Why is this happening?
How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mod_dir and `DirectorySlash` interfering with your URI. When Apache sees that your URI is pointing to a directory but is missing the trailing slash, it will 301 redirect the client to the same URI with the trailing slash. Your rule is being applied, the mod_dir sees that `/aa/b` is a directory so it redirects the browser to `/aa/b/`. You'll just need to check for the trailing slash in your rul:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/(.*?)/?$ xyz/$2/?first-dir=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm very glad to know about `DirectorySlash`. 
Your RewriteRule works. 
But I also wanted to rewrite `/aa/any.php` to `xyz/any.php?first-dir=aa`.
The following code make it possible to do that: 
 `DirectorySlash Off`
 `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index\.php -f`
 `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/index.php [L]`
 `RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])(/.*$|$) xyz$2?first-dir=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

If URL with / `index.php` will be execute

Fixed bugs:
`RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])/(.*)$ xyz/$2/index.php?first-dir=$1 [L]`